# How should I correctly parse this data in to a struct to avoid the "expression expected" error/warning and successfully build the JSON?

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm writing a test program in Go, which takes 5 inputs and will marshal it to JSON and then return it back to the caller.

The JSON structure is defined externally to me so I'm unable to simplify it - even though I reckon it needs it - so I just have to deal with the annoying structure of the payload.

Trouble is, I cannot get it to parse/initialise correctly at all. It keeps complaining about "expected expression" and I can't work out why.

It's worth noting that I had to use one of those JSON-to-struct generators as I couldn't work out what the struct should actually look like, then I tried to clean it up a bit. There could be an error here I'm not seeing.

#### json

```json
{
    "outer": [
        {
            "inner": {
                "key1": "...",
                "key2": "...",
                "key3": "...",
                "key4": "...",
                "key5": "..."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### structs

```golang
type Payload struct {
    Outer []struct {
        Inner InnerTestData `json:"inner"`
    } `json:"outer"`
}

type InnerTestData struct {
    Alertname   string `json:"key1"`
    QueueInHrs  string `json:"key2"`
    QueueOutHrs string `json:"key3"`
    Urgency     string `json:"key4"`
    Impact      string `json:"key5"`
}
```

#### code

```golang
func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 5 {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: There should be 5 args")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    key1 := os.Args[1]
    key2 := os.Args[2]
    key3 := os.Args[3]
    key4 := os.Args[4]
    key5 := os.Args[5]

    innerTestData := InnerTestData{
        Key1: key1,
        Key2: key2,
        Key3: key3,
        Key4: key4,
        Key5: key5,
    }

    payload := Payload{
        Outer: []struct{
            Inner: innerTestData,
        },
    }
}
```

I'm just confused as to how I should actually be parsing this in to the Payload struct, I've tried every combination I can think of without any luck. I'm aware this is probably something simple going wrong, but the whole having to create a struct that perfectly matches the JSON payload situation is really over-complicated and confusing, I find.

Any help appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: The issue is with marshalling the data not unmarshalling. The program takes 5 inputs and should write the JSON encoded output with those 5 values. But I can't get the struct to play nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following composite literal:

```
payload := Payload{
    Outer: []struct {
        Inner InnerTestData `json:"inner"`
    }{
        {Inner: innerTestData},
    },
}
```

Note that the composite literal for the inner struct variable must be surrounded by {}.

A composite literal with an anonymous struct type is verbose.  The type must be repeated in the literal. Simplify by replacing the anonymous type with a named type.

```
type Outer struct {  // <-- new named type
    Inner InnerTestData `json:"inner"`
}

type Payload struct {
    Outer []Outer `json:"outer"` // <-- use it here
}
```

The composite literal with the named type is:

```
payload := Payload{
    Outer: []Outer{
        {Inner: innerTestData},
    },
}
```

The compiler reports an error for  `Outer: []struct{ Inner: innerTestData, }` because the compiler expects a struct definition following the struct keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked exactly how I needed it to work. Great advice as well!